# get value of a property o => o.Property1 , defined in lambda

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to get the value of a property defined in a lambda

```
 public static MvcHtmlString MyHelper<T, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<T> html,
            Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> prop)
        {
            var value = \\ get the value of Prop1 (not the name "Prop1")
          ...
        }
```

the intended usage is something like:

```
public class FooViewModel 
{
    public string Prop1 { get;set; }
}
```

---

```
<%@ Page ViewPage<FooViewModel> %>

<%=Html.MyHelper(o => o.Prop1) %>
```

Comment: The value of a property?  o=> o.Name will return the value.

Comment: The property name or the value of "Name"?

Comment: @yodaj007, @maartenba the property value, not name

Comment: Not completely sure, but this should work: `var value = prop.Compile().Invoke(html.ViewData.Model);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why do you need expression here? If you only want to have property value, `Func<T, TProperty>`  is sufficient - it is like any other delegate, just invoke it:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyHelper<T, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<T> html,
    Func<T, TProperty> prop)
{
    var obj = // ??
    var value = prop(obj); \\ get the value of Prop1 (not the name "Prop1")
    ...
}
```

Where `obj` is the object from which you want to read the value (I can't see the object around your code).

Comment: I think you forgot to change the argument type to `Func<T, TProperty>`, as the expression needs to be compiled before invoking.

Answer (score 8):

You could do it Jim's way or just do this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyHelper<T, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<T> html, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> prop)
    {
        var func = prop.Compile();
        var value = func(html.ViewData.Model);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Omu,

here you go (i'm assuming you mean the actual name derived from the lambda property):

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<TSource, TMember>(
        this Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> memberReference)
    {
        var expression = memberReference.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (expression == null)
        {
            var convertexp = memberReference.Body as UnaryExpression;
            if (convertexp != null)
                expression = convertexp.Operand as MemberExpression; ;
        }
        if (expression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("memberReference");

        return expression.Member.Name;
    }

    private static string GetPropertyName(MethodCallExpression expression)
    {
        var methodCallExpression = expression.Object as MethodCallExpression;
        if (methodCallExpression != null)
        {
            return GetPropertyName(methodCallExpression);
        }
        return expression.Object.ToString();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
string propertyName = prop.GetPropertyName();
```

enjoy..

**[edit]** - just saw that it's the value that you're after. here's a little bit lifted from the subsonic project that does this for you:

```
// 
//   SubSonic - http://subsonicproject.com
// 
//   The contents of this file are subject to the New BSD
//   License (the "License"); you may not use this file
//   except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
//   the License at http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php
//  
//   Software distributed under the License is distributed on an 
//   "AS IS" basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, either express or
//   implied. See the License for the specific language governing
//   rights and limitations under the License.
// 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using SubSonic.Query;

namespace SubSonic.Extensions
{
    public class ExpressionParser
    {
        private const string contains = "Contains";
        private const string endsWith = "EndsWith";
        private const string nullableType = "Nullable`1";
        private const string op_Equality = "op_Equality";
        private const string op_GreaterThan = "op_GreaterThan";
        private const string op_GreaterThanOrEqual = "op_GreaterThanOrEqual";
        private const string op_LessThan = "op_LessThan";
        private const string op_LessThanOrEqual = "op_LessThanOrEqual";
        private const string startsWith = "StartsWith";
        private readonly List<Constraint> result;

        public ExpressionParser()
        {
            result = new List<Constraint>();
        }


        #region Process expressions

        /// <summary>
        /// Process the passed-in LINQ expression
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="expression"></param>
        public List<Constraint> ProcessExpression(Expression expression)
        {
            if(expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso)
                ProcessAndAlso((BinaryExpression)expression);
            else if(expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.NotEqual)
                BuildFromBinary(expression, Comparison.NotEquals);
            else if(expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Equal)
                BuildFromBinary(expression, Comparison.Equals);
            else if(expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.GreaterThan)
                BuildFromBinary(expression, Comparison.GreaterThan);
            else if(expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual)
                BuildFromBinary(expression, Comparison.LessOrEquals);
            else if(expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.LessThan)
                BuildFromBinary(expression, Comparison.LessThan);
            else if(expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual)
                BuildFromBinary(expression, Comparison.LessOrEquals);
            else if(expression is MethodCallExpression)
                ProcessMethodCall((MethodCallExpression)expression);
            else if(expression is LambdaExpression)
                ProcessExpression(((LambdaExpression)expression).Body);
            //else if (expression is MethodCallExpression)
            //    ProcessMethodCall(expression as MethodCallExpression);
            return result;
        }

        private void ProcessAndAlso(BinaryExpression andAlso)
        {
            ProcessExpression(andAlso.Left);
            ProcessExpression(andAlso.Right);
        }

        private void AddConstraint(string columnName, Comparison comp, object value)
        {
            Constraint c = new Constraint(ConstraintType.Where, columnName);

            if(result.Count > 1)
                c = new Constraint(ConstraintType.And, columnName);

            //c.ParameterName = columnName;

            if(comp == Comparison.StartsWith)
            {
                value = string.Format("{0}%", value);
                comp = Comparison.Like;
            }
            else if(comp == Comparison.EndsWith)
            {
                value = string.Format("%{0}", value);
                comp = Comparison.Like;
            }

            c.Comparison = comp;
            c.ParameterValue = value;

            result.Add(c);
        }

        private void BuildFromBinary(Expression exp, Comparison op)
        {

            BinaryExpression expression = exp as BinaryExpression;

            if (expression != null)
            {
                //make sure the left side is a Member, and the right is a constant value
                if(expression.Left is MemberExpression && expression.Right is ConstantExpression)
                {
                    //the member - "Title", "Publisher", etc
                    MemberExpression memb = expression.Left as MemberExpression;
                    //the setting
                    ConstantExpression val = expression.Right as ConstantExpression;
                    AddConstraint(memb.Member.Name, op, val.Value);
                }
                    //or the left side is a Member, and the right is a conversion from a constant value to a nullable
                else if(expression.Left is MemberExpression && expression.Right.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert
                        && expression.Right.Type.Name.Equals(nullableType))
                {
                    //the member - "Title", "Publisher", etc
                    MemberExpression memb = expression.Left as MemberExpression;
                    //the auto-conversion-to-nullable
                    UnaryExpression convert = expression.Right as UnaryExpression;
                    //the setting
                    if (convert != null)
                    {
                        ConstantExpression val = convert.Operand as ConstantExpression;
                        if(val != null)
                            AddConstraint(memb.Member.Name, op, val.Value);
                    }
                }
                    //if this isn't the case, it's Unary and is an enum setting
                else if(expression.Left.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
                {
                    MemberExpression left = expression.Left as MemberExpression;
                    MemberExpression right = expression.Right as MemberExpression;

                    if (right != null)
                    {
                        if (right.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
                        {
                            ConstantExpression val = right.Expression as ConstantExpression;
                            if(val != null && left != null)
                            {
                                Type t = val.Value.GetType();
                                FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields();
                                object oVal = fields[0].GetValue(val.Value);
                                AddConstraint(left.Member.Name, op, oVal);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (right.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
                        {
                            //this is screwed
                            MemberExpression val = right.Expression as MemberExpression;
                            //object expressionValue = EvaluateExpression(val.Expression);
                            //expressionValue.GetType().InvokeMember(val.Member.Name, global, global, expressionValue) ;

                            var t = right.Member.MemberType;

                            //this should be a property
                            //PropertyInfo p = (PropertyInfo)t.GetProperties()[0].GetValue(right.Member, null);
                            //oVal = p.GetValue(val.Member, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void BuildFromMemberAccess(Expression exp, Comparison op)
        {
            MethodCallExpression expression = exp as MethodCallExpression;

            if (expression != null)
            {
                if(expression.Arguments[0].NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
                {
                    MemberExpression memberExpr = (MemberExpression)expression.Arguments[0];
                    if(expression.Arguments[1].NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
                    {
                        ConstantExpression val = (ConstantExpression)expression.Arguments[1];
                        AddConstraint(memberExpr.Member.Name, op, val.Value);
                    }
                }
                else if(expression.Arguments[0].NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
                {
                    ConstantExpression val = (ConstantExpression)expression.Arguments[0];
                    MemberExpression memberExpr = (MemberExpression)expression.Object;
                    AddConstraint(memberExpr.Member.Name, op, val.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ProcessMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expression)
        {
            switch(expression.Method.Name)
            {
                case op_Equality:
                    // Handle book.Publisher == "xxx"
                    BuildFromMemberAccess(expression, Comparison.Equals);
                    break;
                case op_GreaterThan:
                    // Handle book.Price <= xxx
                    BuildFromMemberAccess(expression, Comparison.GreaterThan);
                    break;
                case op_LessThan:
                    // Handle book.Price <= xxx
                    BuildFromMemberAccess(expression, Comparison.LessThan);
                    break;
                case op_LessThanOrEqual:
                    // Handle book.Price <= xxx
                    BuildFromMemberAccess(expression, Comparison.LessOrEquals);
                    break;
                case op_GreaterThanOrEqual:
                    // Handle book.Price <= xxx
                    BuildFromMemberAccess(expression, Comparison.GreaterOrEquals);
                    break;
                case contains:
                    BuildFromMemberAccess(expression, Comparison.Like);
                    break;
                case startsWith:
                    BuildFromMemberAccess(expression, Comparison.StartsWith);
                    break;
                case endsWith:
                    // Handle book.Title.Contains("xxx")
                    BuildFromMemberAccess(expression, Comparison.EndsWith);
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion Process expressions
    }
}
```

usage:

```
private static string ParseExpression(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    var parse = new SubSonic.Extensions.ExpressionParser();
    IList expList = parse.ProcessExpression(expression);
    string expressionParsed = "";
    foreach (SubSonic.Query.Constraint s in expList)
    {
        expressionParsed += string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", s.ColumnName, s.Comparison, s.ParameterValue);
    }
    return expressionParsed;
}
```

tha above ParseExpression() should allow you to find out most anything you need about your Expression.

Comment: I need the value not the name, The name I get with ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(prop)

Comment: it would be really helpful for me to know why the downtick occurred. i'm just an ignorant country boy trying to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

Omu,

Darn the 30k limit here :). had to add the constrint class as a seperate answer. grr..

```
// 
//   SubSonic - http://subsonicproject.com
// 
//   The contents of this file are subject to the New BSD
//   License (the "License"); you may not use this file
//   except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
//   the License at http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php
//  
//   Software distributed under the License is distributed on an 
//   "AS IS" basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, either express or
//   implied. See the License for the specific language governing
//   rights and limitations under the License.
// 
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using SubSonic.Extensions;

namespace SubSonic.Query
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Where, And, Or
    /// </summary>
    public enum ConstraintType
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// WHERE operator
        /// </summary>
        Where,
        /// <summary>
        /// AND operator
        /// </summary>
        And,
        /// <summary>
        /// OR Operator
        /// </summary>
        Or
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// SQL Comparison Operators
    /// </summary>
    public enum Comparison
    {
        Equals,
        NotEquals,
        Like,
        NotLike,
        GreaterThan,
        GreaterOrEquals,
        LessThan,
        LessOrEquals,
        Blank,
        Is,
        IsNot,
        In,
        NotIn,
        OpenParentheses,
        CloseParentheses,
        BetweenAnd,
        StartsWith,
        EndsWith
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for the SqlComparison class
    /// </summary>
    public class SqlComparison
    {
        public const string BLANK = " ";
        public const string EQUAL = " = ";
        public const string GREATER = " > ";
        public const string GREATER_OR_EQUAL = " >= ";
        public const string IS = " IS ";
        public const string IS_NOT = " IS NOT ";
        public const string LESS = " < ";
        public const string LESS_OR_EQUAL = " <= ";
        public const string LIKE = " LIKE ";
        public const string NOT_EQUAL = " <> ";
        public const string NOT_LIKE = " NOT LIKE ";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A Class for handling SQL Constraint generation
    /// </summary>
    public class Constraint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The query that this constraint is operating on
        /// </summary>
        public SqlQuery query;

        public Constraint() {}


        #region Factory methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Constraint"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">The condition.</param>
        /// <param name="constraintColumnName">Name of the constraint column.</param>
        public Constraint(ConstraintType condition, string constraintColumnName)
        {
            Condition = condition;
            ColumnName = constraintColumnName;
            QualifiedColumnName = constraintColumnName;
            ConstructionFragment = constraintColumnName;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Constraint"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">The condition.</param>
        /// <param name="constraintColumnName">Name of the constraint column.</param>
        /// <param name="constraintQualifiedColumnName">Name of the constraint qualified column.</param>
        public Constraint(ConstraintType condition, string constraintColumnName, string constraintQualifiedColumnName)
        {
            Condition = condition;
            ColumnName = constraintColumnName;
            QualifiedColumnName = constraintQualifiedColumnName;
            ConstructionFragment = constraintColumnName;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Constraint"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">The condition.</param>
        /// <param name="constraintColumnName">Name of the constraint column.</param>
        /// <param name="constraintQualifiedColumnName">Name of the constraint qualified column.</param>
        /// <param name="constraintConstructionFragment">The constraint construction fragment.</param>
        public Constraint(ConstraintType condition, string constraintColumnName, string constraintQualifiedColumnName, string constraintConstructionFragment)
        {
            Condition = condition;
            ColumnName = constraintColumnName;
            QualifiedColumnName = constraintQualifiedColumnName;
            ConstructionFragment = constraintConstructionFragment;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Constraint"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">The condition.</param>
        /// <param name="constraintColumnName">Name of the constraint column.</param>
        /// <param name="sqlQuery">The SQL query.</param>
        public Constraint(ConstraintType condition, string constraintColumnName, SqlQuery sqlQuery)
        {
            Condition = condition;
            ColumnName = constraintColumnName;
            QualifiedColumnName = constraintColumnName;
            ConstructionFragment = constraintColumnName;
            query = sqlQuery;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Constraint"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="condition">The condition.</param>
        /// <param name="constraintColumnName">Name of the constraint column.</param>
        /// <param name="constraintQualifiedColumnName">Name of the constraint qualified column.</param>
        /// <param name="constraintConstructionFragment">The constraint construction fragment.</param>
        /// <param name="sqlQuery">The SQL query.</param>
        public Constraint(ConstraintType condition, string constraintColumnName, string constraintQualifiedColumnName, string constraintConstructionFragment, SqlQuery sqlQuery)
        {
            Condition = condition;
            ColumnName = constraintColumnName;
            QualifiedColumnName = constraintQualifiedColumnName;
            ConstructionFragment = constraintConstructionFragment;
            query = sqlQuery;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wheres the specified column name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnName">Name of the column.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Constraint Where(string columnName)
        {
            return new Constraint(ConstraintType.Where, columnName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ands the specified column name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnName">Name of the column.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Constraint And(string columnName)
        {
            return new Constraint(ConstraintType.And, columnName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ors the specified column name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnName">Name of the column.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Constraint Or(string columnName)
        {
            return new Constraint(ConstraintType.Or, columnName);
        }

        #endregion


        #region props

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the table.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The name of the table.</value>
        private string _tableName = String.Empty;

        private ConstraintType condition = ConstraintType.Where;
        private string parameterName;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the condition.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The condition.</value>
        public ConstraintType Condition
        {
            get { return condition; }
            set { condition = value; }
        }

        public string TableName
        {
            get { return _tableName; }
            set { _tableName = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the column.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The name of the column.</value>
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the fully qualified name of the column.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The name of the column.</value>
        public string QualifiedColumnName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the string fragment used when assembling the text of query.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The construction fragment.</value>
        public string ConstructionFragment { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the comparison.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The comparison.</value>
        public Comparison Comparison { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the parameter value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The parameter value.</value>
        public object ParameterValue { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the start value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The start value.</value>
        public object StartValue { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the end value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The end value.</value>
        public object EndValue { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the in values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The in values.</value>
        public IEnumerable InValues { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the in select.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The in select.</value>
        public SqlQuery InSelect { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name of the parameter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The name of the parameter.</value>
        public string ParameterName
        {
            get { return parameterName ?? ColumnName; }
            set { parameterName = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the type of the db.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The type of the db.</value>
        public DbType DbType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this constraint is an Aggregate.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        ///     <c>true</c> if this instance is aggregate; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </value>
        public bool IsAggregate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the comparison operator.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="comp">The comp.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetComparisonOperator(Comparison comp)
        {
            string sOut;
            switch(comp)
            {
                case Comparison.Blank:
                    sOut = SqlComparison.BLANK;
                    break;
                case Comparison.GreaterThan:
                    sOut = SqlComparison.GREATER;
                    break;
                case Comparison.GreaterOrEquals:
                    sOut = SqlComparison.GREATER_OR_EQUAL;
                    break;
                case Comparison.LessThan:
                    sOut = SqlComparison.LESS;
                    break;
                case Comparison.LessOrEquals:
                    sOut = SqlComparison.LESS_OR_EQUAL;
                    break;
                case Comparison.Like:
                    sOut = SqlComparison.LIKE;
                    break;
                case Comparison.NotEquals:
                    sOut = SqlComparison.NOT_EQUAL;
                    break;
                case Comparison.NotLike:
                    sOut = SqlComparison.NOT_LIKE;
                    break;
                case Comparison.Is:
                    sOut = SqlComparison.IS;
                    break;
                case Comparison.IsNot:
                    sOut = SqlComparison.IS_NOT;
                    break;
                case Comparison.OpenParentheses:
                    sOut = "(";
                    break;
                case Comparison.CloseParentheses:
                    sOut = ")";
                    break;
                case Comparison.In:
                    sOut = " IN ";
                    break;
                case Comparison.NotIn:
                    sOut = " NOT IN ";
                    break;
                default:
                    sOut = SqlComparison.EQUAL;
                    break;
            }
            return sOut;
        }

        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified <see cref="T:System.Object"/> is equal to the current <see cref="T:System.Object"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The <see cref="T:System.Object"/> to compare with the current <see cref="T:System.Object"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if the specified <see cref="T:System.Object"/> is equal to the current <see cref="T:System.Object"/>; otherwise, false.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.NullReferenceException">The <paramref name="obj"/> parameter is null.</exception>
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if(obj is Constraint)
            {
                Constraint compareTo = (Constraint)obj;
                return compareTo.ParameterName.Matches(parameterName) &&
                       compareTo.ParameterValue.Equals(ParameterValue);
            }
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serves as a hash function for a particular type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A hash code for the current <see cref="T:System.Object"/>.
        /// </returns>
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a LIKE statement.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val">The val.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery Like(string val)
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.Like;
            ParameterValue = val;
            DbType = query.GetConstraintDbType(TableName, ColumnName, val);
            query.Constraints.Add(this);

            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a LIKE statement and appends a wildcard to the end of the passed-in value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val">The val.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery StartsWith(string val)
        {
            return StartsWith(val, "%");
        }

        public SqlQuery StartsWith(string val, string wildCard)
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.Like;
            ParameterValue = String.Format("{0}{1}", val, wildCard);
            DbType = query.GetConstraintDbType(TableName, ColumnName, val);
            query.Constraints.Add(this);

            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a LIKE statement and appends a wildcard to the end of the passed-in value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val">The val.</param>
        /// <param name="wildCard">The wild card.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery EndsWith(string val, string wildCard)
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.Like;
            ParameterValue = String.Format("{0}{1}", wildCard, val);
            DbType = query.GetConstraintDbType(TableName, ColumnName, val);
            query.Constraints.Add(this);

            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a LIKE statement and appends a wildcard to the end of the passed-in value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val">The val.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery EndsWith(string val)
        {
            return EndsWith(val, "%");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a NOT LIKE statement
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val">The val.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery NotLike(string val)
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.NotLike;
            ParameterValue = val;
            DbType = query.GetConstraintDbType(TableName, ColumnName, val);
            query.Constraints.Add(this);

            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether [is greater than] [the specified val].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val">The val.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery IsGreaterThan(object val)
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.GreaterThan;
            ParameterValue = val;
            DbType = query.GetConstraintDbType(TableName, ColumnName, val);
            query.Constraints.Add(this);

            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether [is greater than] [the specified val].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val">The val.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(object val)
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.GreaterOrEquals;
            ParameterValue = val;
            DbType = query.GetConstraintDbType(TableName, ColumnName, val);
            query.Constraints.Add(this);

            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies a SQL IN statement using a nested Select statement
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="selectQuery">The select query.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery In(SqlQuery selectQuery)
        {
            //validate that there is only one column in the columnlist
            if(selectQuery.SelectColumnList.Length == 0 || selectQuery.SelectColumnList.Length > 1)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("You must specify a column to return for the IN to be valid. Use Select(\"column\") to do this");

            InSelect = selectQuery;

            Comparison = Comparison.In;
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies a SQL IN statement
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="vals">Value array</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery In(IEnumerable vals)
        {
            InValues = vals;
            Comparison = Comparison.In;
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies a SQL IN statement
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="vals">Value array</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery In(params object[] vals)
        {
            InValues = vals;
            Comparison = Comparison.In;
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
            //this is trickery, since every time we send in a Select query, it will call this method
            //so we need to evaluate it, and call In(Select)
            //I don't like this hack, but don't see a way around it
            /*
            if(vals.Length > 0)
            {
                if(vals[0].ToString().StartsWith("SELECT"))
                {
                    Select s = (Select)vals[0];
                    query = In(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    InValues = vals;
                    Comparison = Comparison.In;
                    query.Constraints.Add(this);
                }
            }

            return query;*/
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies a SQL IN statement using a nested Select statement
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="selectQuery">The select query.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery NotIn(SqlQuery selectQuery)
        {
            //validate that there is only one column in the columnlist
            if(selectQuery.SelectColumnList.Length == 0 || selectQuery.SelectColumnList.Length > 1)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("You must specify a column to return for the IN to be valid. Use Select(\"column\") to do this");

            InSelect = selectQuery;

            Comparison = Comparison.NotIn;
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies a SQL Not IN statement
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="vals">Value array</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery NotIn(IEnumerable vals)
        {
            InValues = vals;
            Comparison = Comparison.NotIn;
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies a SQL NOT IN statement
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="vals">Value array</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery NotIn(params object[] vals)
        {
            InValues = vals;
            Comparison = Comparison.NotIn;
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
                /*
            if(vals.Length > 0)
            {
                if(vals[0].ToString().StartsWith("SELECT"))
                {
                    Select s = (Select)vals[0];
                    query = NotIn(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    InValues = vals;
                    Comparison = Comparison.NotIn;
                    query.Constraints.Add(this);
                }
            }
            return query;*/
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether [is less than] [the specified val].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val">The val.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery IsLessThan(object val)
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.LessThan;
            ParameterValue = val;
            DbType = query.GetConstraintDbType(TableName, ColumnName, val);
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether [is less than] [the specified val].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val">The val.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery IsLessThanOrEqualTo(object val)
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.LessOrEquals;
            ParameterValue = val;
            DbType = query.GetConstraintDbType(TableName, ColumnName, val);
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether [is not null] [the specified val].
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery IsNotNull()
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.IsNot;
            ParameterValue = DBNull.Value;
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified val is null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery IsNull()
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.Is;
            ParameterValue = DBNull.Value;
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether [is between and] [the specified val1].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val1">The val1.</param>
        /// <param name="val2">The val2.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery IsBetweenAnd(object val1, object val2)
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.BetweenAnd;
            StartValue = val1;
            EndValue = val2;
            DbType = query.GetConstraintDbType(TableName, ColumnName, val1);
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether [is equal to] [the specified val].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val">The val.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery IsEqualTo(object val)
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.Equals;
            ParameterValue = val;
            DbType = query.GetConstraintDbType(TableName, ColumnName, val);
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether [is not equal to] [the specified val].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="val">The val.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SqlQuery IsNotEqualTo(object val)
        {
            Comparison = Comparison.NotEquals;
            ParameterValue = val;
            DbType = query.GetConstraintDbType(TableName, ColumnName, val);
            query.Constraints.Add(this);
            return query;
        }
    }
}
```

join with previous answer and cook for 2 seconds... sorry this 'answer' is so verbose, this is all normally wrapped in subsonic, so is a one liner for me.